# How to handle an exception "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I've made an UltraGrid with Infragistics where I have a column of Datetime type with the format HH:mm.

Normally the column is filled with a value like : "15:13". I can edit it and set what I want then save. But if I delete the field it looks like that : "_ *:* _" then I save my table, I get back an exception "Specified cast is not valid".

This is because I'm trying to save a value which is not set. I would like to know how to handle this exception.

I tried to compare the fiel to "null" but it does not work.

```
var newDuration = (DateTime)row.GetCellValue(3);
if (newDuration == null)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Please set all the fields.");
}
```

The dataType of the column is System.DateTime, I set the default value to DB (DBNull) and AllowDBNull is Default.

There are two ways to fix the issue:

- display a message to the user to ask him to set a value
- If the field is empty, set a default value like 00:00

Ask me if you need more info. Thanks !

Comment: Use Datetime.TryParse

Comment: What does `row.GetCellValue(3).GetType()` show?

Comment: If it Nullable field than try using Nullable DateTime type. 
var newDuration = (DateTime?)row.GetCellValue(3);  check for null first.

Comment: @Jon Skeet it shows "{03/01/2015 00:00:00}

Comment: I very, very much doubt that `row.GetCellValue(3).GetType()` shows that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Haha my bad ! I told you the value of the cell ^^Here the type :{Name = "DateTime" FullName = "System.DateTime"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: @Nps I tried with DateTime? and did this :`var newDuration = (DateTime?)row.GetCellValue(3);
                if (newDuration == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }`
But it does not show the message.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath I do not know how to handle the case if the field is "_ _:_ _". I donno how to catch it in a "if" statement.

Comment: @Majestic if you check the method I am referring to, it does have an out parameter which tells you if the field is date or not.

Comment: in this case newDuration will not be null, check newDuration.Value property for null

Comment: If it's *really* a DateTime, it should cast with no problems. So my guess is that you're looking at one of the values that *doesn't* cause a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did this :

```
try
{
       newDuration = (DateTime)row.GetCellValue(3);
}
catch
{
       row.SetCellValue(3, new DateTime());
       newDuration = (DateTime)row.GetCellValue(3);
}
```

And it works... Thanks all for your help, I will use what you told in my future dev' !

Comment: Very bad choice. Letting the exception drive your code will result in a noticeable performance hit particularly if you have many rows to check

Answer (score 1):

Typical pattern to try to get value of wanted type without being sure is

```
var value = someOtherValue as SomeType;
if (value != null)
{
    ... // value is a correct SomeType here
}
```

This works for reference types. In case of structures (`DateTime` is a structure), which are value types, you'll have to check the type prior

```
var value = row.GetCellValue(3);
if(value is DateTime)
{
    var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
    ... // dateTime is a valid DateTime here
}
```

My answer doesn't explain why you have the problem, but shows how to avoid having it (which may not be a good idea, but it seems you want that).

If your value can be `DBNull`, then simply check for it:

```
var value = row.GetCellValue(3);
if(value != DBNull.Value)
{
    var dateTime = (DateTime)value; // it must work now
    ...
}
```

Comment: I bet money most of his rows is a `DateTime` but some of them are `DbNull.Value` and that is the value it is failing on.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You lost money man, I have only two columns of DateTime which the type is to System.DateTime. But the defaultValue is DBNull, does it matter ?

Comment: Yes that does matter. You have some rows that are null, those rows do not show up as `null` but instead as `DbNull.Value`.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes it could be a good to check the type. But this is the value that I want to test. I'm a rookie on C#... :/

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I change it by DateTime and it set a default value like "01/01/2015 00:00:00" ok that's fine. But when I let my field empty and try to save it does not change the empty field with the default one. And returns me an exception.

Comment: Yes, default value is for **new** rows, if you explicitly send in a empty value it will still save it as `DbNull`

Answer (score 0):

At the wingrid there is a specific event for handling this errors, its datacellerror quite useful and no need of anything else, hope this its helpfull for someone